# How do I do a Pagination on a httpPost ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination

I'm pretty new to mvc, I am having an issue with paginating a list from a search result. Here's what I have tried so far: This is the search Business Logic:

```
  public IQueryable<IGrouping<int, LLATTRDATA>> GetDocuments(DocumentSearchInputModel searchInputModel)
        {
            try
            {
                _entities = new Entities();
                Logger.Info("connection to db successfull" + _entities);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
              Logger.Error(e);
            }

            if (_entities != null)
            {

                var result = _entities.LLATTRDATAs.AsQueryable();

                //Group Ids together
                var ids = _entities.LLATTRDATAs.Where(r => r.VALSTR.Contains(searchInputModel.OwnersName) && r.ATTRID == 2)
                .Select(r => r.ID);
                Logger.Debug("the Ids are "+ids);

                var selected = _entities.LLATTRDATAs.Where(r => ids.Contains(r.ID)).GroupBy(r => r.ID);
                Logger.Debug("the selected Ids are "+ selected);


                if (searchInputModel != null)
                {
                    //result =
                    foreach (var selectedId in selected)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in selectedId)
                        {
                            item.DATAID = (
                               from l
                                   in _entities.LLATTRDATAs
                               join d
                                   in _entities.DTREEs
                                   on l.ID
                                   equals d.DATAID
                               join v
                                   in _entities.DVERSDATAs
                                   on d.VERSIONNUM
                                   equals v.VERSION
                               where d.DATAID == v.DOCID && l.ATTRID == 2
                                     && l.VALSTR.Contains(searchInputModel.OwnersName) && l.VERNUM == v.VERSION
                               select l.ID).ToList().FirstOrDefault();

                            Logger.Info("DataID is "+ item.DATAID);

                            PROVIDERDATA providerData = (
                                from p
                                    in _entities.PROVIDERDATAs
                                join v
                                    in _entities.DVERSDATAs on p.PROVIDERID
                                    equals v.PROVIDERID
                                where v.DOCID == item.DATAID && v.VERSION == 1
                                select p).FirstOrDefault();
                            Logger.Info("provider data is "+ providerData);

                            //Get the needed string from the full path
                            Regex regexForUsefulUrl = new Regex("(?<==')(.*)(?=','st)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
                            if (providerData != null)
                            {
                                var getUsefulUrl = regexForUsefulUrl.Matches(providerData.PROVIDERDATA1);
                                var useFulUrl = getUsefulUrl[0].Value;
                                Logger.Debug("Needed URL is:", new Exception(useFulUrl));
                                item.FILECONTENT = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerUrl"] + useFulUrl;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                   // if (getFileUrl != null) searchInputModel.FileUrl = getFileUrl.providerType;
                }
                Logger.Info($"Results found {result}");

                return selected;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Now This is the search controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Request.QueryString != null && Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
        {
            return View();
        }
        return null;

    }

    [HttpPost]
    [HandleError]
    public ActionResult Index(DocumentSearchInputModel searchInputModel, int page = 0)
    {
        _entities = new Entities();
        const int pageSize = 2;

        var business = new SearchBusinessLogic();
        var model = business.GetDocuments(searchInputModel);

        var count = model.Count();

        var data = model.OrderBy(i => i.Key).Skip(page * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
        //TempData["data"] = data;

        TempData["data"] = data;
        Session.Add("data", data);

        ViewBag.MaxPage = (count / pageSize) - (count % pageSize == 0 ? 1 : 0);

        ViewBag.Page = page;


        //save user search inputs to the db
        using (var db = new LagosOnlineESearchEntities())
        {
            var pin = TempData["UserPin"];
            var result = db.UserSearchInformations.SingleOrDefault(b => b.ReceiptNumber == (string)pin);
            if (result != null)
            {
                if (searchInputModel != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                     result.SearchByOwnersName = searchInputModel.OwnersName;
                                            result.SearchByOwnersAddress = searchInputModel.OwnersAddress;
                                            result.SearchByVolumeNumber = searchInputModel.VolumeNumber;
                                            result.SearchBySurveyPlanNumber = searchInputModel.SurveyPlanNumber;
                                            result.SearchByDescriptionOrLocationOfProperty = searchInputModel.DescriptionOrLocationOfProp;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {

                        Logger.Error("Error", e);
                    }

                }
                Logger.Info("Details about to be to save");
                db.SaveChanges();
                Logger.Info("User search inputs saved to the db");
            }
        }
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) {

            return View(searchInputModel);
        }
        return View("searchResult", data);

    }
```

Note: The HttpGet Index displays the search input fields(It is multi-search)

And this is my view (the part that I am having the issue):

```
 @if (ViewBag.Page > 0)
                {
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Search", new {page = ViewBag.Page  - 1})" class="btn btn-danger btn-fill">&laquo; PREV</a>
                }

                @if (ViewBag.Page < ViewBag.MaxPage)
                {
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Search", new {page = ViewBag.Page  + 1})" class="btn btn-danger btn-fill">NEXT &laquo;</a>
                }
```

So if I click NEXT, it takes me to the httpGet Search Index (the search input page), and not the remaining search results. Please how do i make this work?

Thanks

I just found another possible route to the solution, by adding a new actionResult method and moving all the codes from the httpPost Index that does the pagination to this method like so:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SearchResult(int page = 0)
    {
        DocumentSearchInputModel searchInputModel = (DocumentSearchInputModel) TempData["data"];

        _entities = new Entities();
        const int pageSize = 2;

        var business = new SearchBusinessLogic();
        var model = business.GetDocuments(searchInputModel);

        var count = model.Count();

        var data = model.OrderBy(i => i.Key).Skip(page * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();

        ViewBag.MaxPage = (count / pageSize) - (count % pageSize == 0 ? 1 : 0);

        ViewBag.Page = page;

        return View("searchResult", data);
    }
```

but the searchInputModel is returning null instead of the user inputs, I've tried tempData, viewbag and viewdata, none seem to be working. So my challenge now is how to pass the user inputs from that index httppost to the new actionresult method. Thanks guys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question: "but the searchInputModel is returning null instead of the user inputs, I've tried tempData, viewbag and viewdata, none seem to be working." It's just because you haven't yet set its value to TempData, ViewBag or ViewData before you call the request.

So, my suggestion is to add the get and set code to this portion:

```
    @if (ViewBag.Page > 0)
        {
            //To get and set user inputs here
            var searchInputModel = new DocumentSearchInputModel();
            ...
            TempData["data"] = searchInputModel;
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Search", new {page = ViewBag.Page  - 1})" class="btn btn-danger btn-fill">&laquo; PREV</a>
        }

@if (ViewBag.Page < ViewBag.MaxPage)
        {
           //To get and set user inputs here
            var searchInputModel = new DocumentSearchInputModel();
            ...
            TempData["data"] = searchInputModel;
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Search", new {page = ViewBag.Page  + 1})" class="btn btn-danger btn-fill">NEXT &laquo;</a>
        }
```

However, I think you're better to have a look at some tutorials, before writing this pagination. This one for example is very good and easy to understand: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Thanks so much!...getting and setting the inputs solved the issue.